# Where is "grants advantage" on the power spectrum?

Tags: dnd-5e

So a question asked a few days ago [here about a lucky coin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/89328/can-i-stop-this-homebrewed-lucky-coin-ability-from-being-exploited), got me thinking..
where, on the spectrum is a weapon that grants advantage to it's rolls?  Lets define the situation as this:

> Advantage weaponary: In any round where you do not have disadvantage on your attack, this weapon gives advantage to its first attack roll of the round.

How does this compare, to say a +2 weapon or a +3 weapon?  I started looking into situations, but it quickly got a bit confusing.

Comment: Although this has been closed as a duplicate, that's good — duplicates give us new ways for people to find the answers to their question when they are searching. So thank you for asking! Should the linked question's answers not answer your question though, do let us know how so that the unanswered part of your question can be emphasised with an [edit] and properly answered.